# GridLayout is only showing the first row

Tags: android, android-layout

So I'm trying to get a GridLayout for buttons in the middle of my app's home screen. I've got 3 rows and 2 columns, but it's only showing the first row and the rest of the image buttons are overflowing past the edge of the screen.

I want to avoid setting the exact size of the GridLayout (which I know fixes the issue) as it could end up on many screens.

Is there some way I can fix this?

Here's what it's doing:

[image: incorrect layout]

This is what it should look like:

[image: correct layout]

And here's my GridLayout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="cursive"
    android:text="@string/appTitle"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/settingsButton"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/emergencyButton"/>

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notesImageButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/notepad" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tasksImageButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/list" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/assignmentsImageButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/project" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/classesImageButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/blackboard" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gradesImageButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/grades" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/achievementsImageButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/trophy" />
</GridLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/settings"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/emergencyButton"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/sos"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by could end up on many screens? Try changing the rowWeights in your image views to 0.33

Comment: Show your whole code of xml.

Comment: @Mars It could be on an older version of Android, it could be on a small screen, a tablet. I don't want to limit the app to a single type of device.

Comment: @Moira What's your current target and minimum SDK?

Comment: Using your code, it looks fine (at least in editor)... Is this only an issue when deployed to a device? Also, what errors/warnings are you getting in the layout editor?

Comment: Every time I emulate it, it comes up the same, and there's no errors or warnings, hence my confusion. I don't want to set the height if I can avoid it but it's looking like I might have to.

Min SDK is 16, target 25

Comment: @Moira Confirmed working with the same SDK settings, but there are definitely not zero warnings. In the editor, look for the little red box above the layout that should have a "9+" in it

Comment: @Mars I went through and resolved all the warnings, and still doing the same thing. I think I'm going to just make a note in the XML file and hard code the height.

Comment: @Moira What device are you emulating? Does it look fine in editor but only breaks while emulating? Or does it not even look fine in editor?

Comment: @Mars Nexus 5X API 25 is my device of choice, and it's doing the same in editor as well as emulator :/

Comment: @Moira Very odd... I literally copied and pasted your code and swapped out the image and strings and it looks fine here. Have you not made changes to the layout since what you posted above? If you've made changes, I'd suggest copying and pasting your above code and checking for errors again

Comment: @Moira last thing I can suggest is to check your compiled app dependencies. Maybe try the lines compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+' , compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+' , compile 'com.android.support:constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

Comment: I have the same problem, but it only happens the first time the gridlayout is loaded. If I go back to a previous screen and reload the screen with the gridlayout it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

and try again that's work with me

Answer (score 0):

You can set `android:layout_height="0dp"`

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    ...                       />
```

And I add the `TextView` you did not provided .

Try this in your code .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notesImageButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/notepad"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tasksImageButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/list"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/assignmentsImageButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/project"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/classesImageButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/blackboard"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gradesImageButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/grades"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/achievementsImageButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/trophy"/>
</GridLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Apologies, I put in the wrong height in the code and fixed it back to the code that isn't working properly which is exactly what you mentioned here.

Comment: I've updated with my full XML and it's still busted.

Comment: You can use LinearLayout .It was more better.

Answer (score 0):

Provided code looks totally fine in editor and on a device.

Check your app compile dependencies: (EX)

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
```